# save part of a file.bin in another flie.bin

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want cut a part of signal.bin then save it (part of signal.bin) in w1.bin

I use these comment

```
f=fopen('signal.bin','rb');
v=fread(f,'float');

w1=v(0.93e8:1.3e8);
figure;plot(w1)
```

I want to save w1 in w1.bin

```
t=fopen('w1.bin', 'w+');
fwrite(t,w1);
fclose(t);
```

I open w1.bin and plot it

```
x=fopen('w1.bin','rb');
z=fread(x,'float');

figure;plot(z);
```

but plot(w1) and plot(z) are not same.
what is problem?

Answer (score 0):

You write it not as single but as double. Matlab will convert anything `fread` reads to a 64-bit floating point value (called `double`). As it says here
https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html

`By default, numeric and character values are returned in class 'double' arrays.`

You read 32-bit floating point values (called `single`) in matlab.

Change it to this maybe:

```
f=fopen('signal.bin','rb');
v=fread(f,'*single'); %keep it single
fclose(f);
pntrs = uint64([0.93e8,1.3e8]); %don't use floating point values as pointers
w1=v(pntrs(1):pntrs(2)); 
t=fopen('w1.bin', 'w+');
fwrite(t,w1);
fclose(t);
```

Comment: thank you. but still plot(w1) and plot(z) are not same.

Comment: can you post an example `signal.bin'? In what way are the plots not the same?